# SQL statement based on reccurrence

Tags: mysql, sql

One table has the following data entries:

```
mm_id, mm_interval, mm_interval_type, mm_start_date, mm_start_hour, mm_end_hour
3,     14,          3,                2013-07-15,    08:22,         03:55
```

mm_interval is as "every"
mm_interval_type is

```
array(
1=>"Hour", 
2=>"Day", 
3=>"Week", 
4=>"Month", 
5=>"Year" 
)
```

Now, what I am looking for, is a way to select the entries that match current date.

/Lars

Comment: You could clarify your question with some examples.  For the one row you listed, is this the interval `2013-07-15 08:22` to `2013-07-22 03:55`?  That's not exactly a week is it?

Comment: where mm_start_date >= currentdate and mm_end_hour <= 23:59 and mm_interval_type = 1

Comment: Are you able to modify the schema?

Comment: Yes, I am able to modify the schema.

And, the recurrence should be calculated from the start_date

So it could be like:
if mm_start_date is 2013-07-15 (it would then be calculated to be an Monday) is should read like "Every 14th Monday"

Comment: Arg.. my wrong.. (Cant even read my own data ;-))
It should read "Every 14th week on the calculated monday"

Answer (score 0):

I think I will alter the question with the result soo far ;-)

```
SELECT
  mm.*,
    mm_recurrence_settings.*
FROM
    mm
LEFT JOIN mm_types USING (mm_type_id)
LEFT JOIN mm_recurrence_settings USING (mm_id)
WHERE
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_interval_type = 1 THEN DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_start_date, INTERVAL mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_interval HOUR)) AND CURDATE( )
            WHEN mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_interval_type = 2 THEN DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_start_date, INTERVAL mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_interval DAY)) AND CURDATE( )
            WHEN mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_interval_type = 3 THEN DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_start_date, INTERVAL mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_interval WEEK)) AND CURDATE( )
            WHEN mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_interval_type = 4 THEN DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_start_date, INTERVAL mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_interval MONTH)) AND CURDATE( )
            WHEN mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_interval_type = 5 THEN DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_start_date, INTERVAL mm_recurrence_settings.mm_reoc_interval YEAR)) AND CURDATE( )
        END as newDate
```

This it where it gets ....

My thought was to use BETWEEN to iterate over the intervals for me. But alas, I only get the first iteration.

Perhaps a stored procedure or?

Comment: Seems that the issue cannot be handled by MySql.